# Ignore expired SSL Certificates in Meteor HTTP Calls

Tags: ssl, meteor

I got an old web app runing Meteor 1.6.1.1 in which we request data from `restcountries.com`. Unfortuanately Meteor now thinks that their certificate has expired. Presumable because of the R3 Certificate that expired a while ago. Since migration/update to another framework is not planned, I wanted to disable certificate verification for now. But I can't figure out how. I've tried setting `strictSSL` to false in the call options, but it doesn't have any effect:

```
var response = HTTP.get(apiUrl, {
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Meteor/1.0", //Required for EUROSTAT provider
        "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    strictSSL: false
}).data;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the env variable of Node: NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED

https://docs.meteor.com/expired-certificate.html

Comment: that seemes to help. Thank you.